# How to initalize a class that inherits interface?

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I'm trying to apply `SOLID` in my code. I've got a Menu with several options. Every menu has some buttons.I'm making a `Interface` for the first menu buttons:

```
interface IConvertToPartListButton
{
    void ConvertToPartList();
}
class BtnConvertToPartList : IConvertToPartListButton
{
   void ConvertToPartList()
   {
        //Do something
   } 
}
```

After that I implement an interface that `inherits` those two buttons I created

```
interface IImportPartsButtons : IConvertToPartListButton,IDeleteIP
{
}
```

So for every menu I will do that. After that I want to inherit all menu buttons :

```
interface IButton : IImportPartsButtons,SecondMenuButtons,ThirdMenuButtons
{
}
```

When I try to make a new instance of the class `BtnConverToPartList` it's not possible.

```
 public static IButton GetButton() => new BtnConvertToPartList();
```

Error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'MOSOSoftware.BtnConvertToPartList' to 'MOSOSoftware.IButton'.
```

If I am doing something wrong please write that down, I'm new to programming and I'm still learning. Thank You!

Comment: `BtnConvertToPartList` does not implement the interface `IButton`?

Comment: You're going in the wrong direction with your inheritance. `IImportPartsButtons` should derive from `IButton` not the other way around.

Comment: Why are you creating an interface per button? And why does IButton inherit all specific button interfaces?

Comment: I'm trying to do that -> Button -> MenuButtons ->MenuButton.
I got 50 buttons. In the first menu I have 3. So I create 3 Interfaces  and combine them in one which is IImportPartsButtons and after that IButton inherit all Menubuttons. Which is unnecessary?

Comment: The exception does not say "creating failed". creation is fine. You request the return value should be IButton, the exception says your created thing is not an IButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong inheritance. "BtnConvertToPartList" implements "IConvertToPartListButton" but "IButton" is not "IConvertToPartListButton" until you implement "IButton" to "IConvertToPartListButton". Please find the changed code below,

```
 interface IConvertToPartListButton : IButton
{
    void ConvertToPartList();
}


interface IImportPartsButtons : IConvertToPartListButton
{
}

interface IButton
{
}

class BtnConvertToPartList : IConvertToPartListButton
{
    public void ConvertToPartList()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

and the instatntiation,

```
public static IButton GetButton() => new BtnConvertToPartList();
```

Now it should work because BtnConvertToPartList is IButton as well because IButton is IConvertToPartListButton.